# While commitEditingStyle in tableView, imageView height goes big overflow?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I find that while swipe Left for commitEditingStyle in tableView, including imageView goes a bit down (overflow), where is my fault? I have added some informations about what I did.

Using auto layouts **0** to each side **Superview**:

[image]

Setting **tableView rowHeight** like this in **viewDidLoad**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // deleting top tableView spacing..
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    // set rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = (self.view.frame.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20) / 4

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}
```

Here's my **commitEditingStyle** func for **tableView**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let city = cities[indexPath.row]
        ad.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(city)
        do {
            try ad.managedObjectContext.save()
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Error deleting item!")
        }

        fetchAndSetResults()

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // ..
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem adding this,

```
cell.recipeImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method while imageView adding.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "Clip Subviews" to your ImageView in the cell, if you have the "Aspect Fill" mode.